# getLineNumber() of StackTraceElement gives -1 value

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-native-interface

I have a exe in C++, through it I am using a jar file through JNI layer utility. both C++ and Java have it's own separate logging functionality, I am facing a unique problem, while logging for Java module, StackTraceElement gives -1 value for getLineNumber() call, while Classname, methodname are proper one, even I tried to print whole stack for each StackTraceElement, getting getLineNumber value as -1. cn't figure out the root cause. any input will be appreciable.

Comment: Did you compile the Java code in the first place?

Comment: yes i have compiled the java code base, it gives no error,

Comment: i will try and let u know, thanxs for ur input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the code was compiled without debugging information included.  From the [`javac` man page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html):

> **-g** 
>   Generate all debugging information, including local variables. By default, only line number and source file information is generated.
>
> **-g:none** 
>   Do not generate any debugging information.
>
> **-g:{keyword list}**
>   Generate only some kinds of debugging information, specified by a comma separated list of keywords. Valid keywords are: 
>   **`source`** Source file debugging information 
>   **`lines`** Line number debugging information 
>   **`vars`** Local variable debugging information

Comment: thanxs for input, it works, i enable debug info in my ant build script and started working.